# What am I doing wrong Ruby on Rails facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, paperclip

This is my user model called "user.rb" and I want that people can sign in with their Facebook account and transfer their profile picture to my website. The problem is that it keeps saying that "user.image" in the "profile_picture" variable is undefined. Ruby stores the image with the paperclip gem.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {in: 2..50}

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first

    if user
      return user
    else
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.fullname = auth.info.name
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email  
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      end
    end
  end

  def profile_picture
    if user.image
      user.image
    else
      has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.jpg"
      validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    end
  end

end
```

In my html.erb file I call the image method with:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

I know I will have to change it to:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.profile_picture %>
```

Here is my schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150927111830) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "fullname"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "image"
  end

  add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Could you paste in your `schema.rb` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` in the `profile_picture` method is out of scope. Whenever you declare a local variable within your method (e.g `user`), this will only be available inside the scope of that method.

`current_user` is an instance of `User` so if you want the image of that user you can simply call in your `image_tag`:
`<%= image_tag(current_user.image) %>`

Comment: I believe that will still be out of scope since one method is a class method and the other is an instance method

Comment: An instance variable is available throughout the class. I am not talking about class methods here please see the differences between class methods and instance method [Here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

Comment: An instance variable is available throughout any instance of a class, but a class method and an instance method are going to be dealing with two different objects. In order for profile_picture to access the instance method in self.from_omniauth, profile_picture would also have to become a class method.

Comment: I changed `if user.image` and `user.image` to `if @user.image` and `@user.image`, but it still doesn't work. It says undefined method `image'.

Comment: But only one problem, if I signup without facebook I can't see my self uploaded image with paperclip because the variable isn't called with  `<%= image_tag(current_user.image) %>`

Comment: whether its a signin via facebook or just regular signin, images should be persisted to the image attribute in the Users table. Isn't that the case for you?